# trying to recive a data using stm32 if the data starts with letter 'a' but thats not happening

Tags: stm32, interrupt, uart, stm32f4discovery

```
uint8_t Rx_data\[10\];
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);`
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef huart2)
{
    if(Rx_data[0] == 'a')
    {
          HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&huart2, Rx_data, 10);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
   HAL_Init();
   SystemClock_Config();
   MX_GPIO_Init();
   MX_USART2_UART_Init();
   while (1)
   {

        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin);
        HAL_Delay(500);
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&huart2, Rx_data, 10);
    }
```

Comment: Your code is very badly formatted and hard to read. But it seems using interrupts here is pointless and is making things more complicated than they need to be. You should just use regular polling receive calls.

Comment: hi bro can we connect some where else i am not able to paste the code

Comment: `char buffer[UART_BUFFER_SIZE];`
`int idx = 0;`
`char start_char = 'A';``void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)`
`{`
 ` if (huart == &huart2) ``{
         `if (buffer[0] == start_char) {
             printf("Received data: %s\r\n", buffer);
         }`
         `idx = 0;`
         `HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (char *) buffer, 10);`
     }`
}` HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *) buffer, 10);`
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  
  }

Comment: he callback will be called after 10 characters received. Your while lop will start it all over again. IT functions do not block. Do not use them before you understand how async programming works

Comment: @MANNEPALLIPOOJITHE0219053 you keep calling HAL_UART_Receive_IT every half a second without stop, even while communication is ongoing. It's not a blocking function. It sets interrupt configs and continues to execute things further. You program resets its own receive mechanism every half a second. Thus, it can't work as expected.